# Visualize Call Stack in VS Code Jupyter Notebook

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger, debuggervisualizer

I was wondering if there is a way to visualize (or list) execution stack in VS Code Jupyter Notebook

This thing can be seen in Google Colab. Hence, whenever you run a function the execution stack is displayed at the bottom

[Screenshot of how it looks in colab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1UT7.png)

I've tried using [Jupyter Lab's Debugger](https://jupyterlab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/debugger.html), but not exactly what I want plus it doesn't work in VS Code